# How to configure RMI over SSL in ehcache for replication

Tags: ssl, replication, ehcache

I Have ehcache replication working properly without SSL support.
I am looking to support my ehcache replication via SSL i.e. i want to have RMI over SSL

How can i do that?

Here is sample manual peer discovery i am using.

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
properties="peerDiscovery=manual,
rmiUrls=//10.100.10.12:40002/ssoSessionStore"/>
```

Can i have some SSL support to RMI call it is doing?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution ??

Comment: Yes. I have modified the source code of ehcache and i maintain on my own .

Comment: So you mean you coded for opening a SSL socket and using RMI over it ?? If not then could you please share what exactly you did ?? Did you find any SSL RMI solution from EhCache ??

Comment: I had to find exact classes to be touced and write extra code to make this SSL flag work. I set my own `ssl flag=true/false` to enable ssl over rmi. 
PS : i set this property as system property

Comment: Where was this flag - `ssl flag` I do not see this flag in any EhCache RMI replication thing and if you set this as system properties then how it is bring referenced by EhCache ?? Can you throw more light, probably write as an answer !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to change ehcache source code and change few classes to support SSL. As when ehcache over rmi bootsup , it registers itself on rmiregistry. I need to start this registery via SSL context

Look at class `RMICacheManagerPeerListener.java` for method `startRegistry()`
This is main class where RMI registry starts. One who is modifying the code needs to understand then ehcache rmi code flow first. Below code is snippet of what has to be done and respectively change other methods.

```
final String SSL= System.getProperty("isSSL");
  protected void startRegistry() throws RemoteException {
        try {
            LOG.info("Trying to Get Exsisting Registry =========>> ");
            if (SSL != null && SSL.equals("ssl"))
                registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(hostName, port.intValue(),
                        new SslRMIClientSocketFactory());
            else
                registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(port.intValue());
            try {
                registry.list();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // may not be created. Let's create it.
                if (SSL != null && SSL.equals("ssl")) {
                    LOG.info("Registry not found, Creating New SSL =========>> ");
                    registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port.intValue(),
                            new SslRMIClientSocketFactory(), new SslRMIServerSocketFactory(null, null, true));
                } else {
                    LOG.info("Registry not found, Creating New Naming registry =========>> ");
                    registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port.intValue());
                }

                registryCreated = true;

            }
        } catch (ExportException exception) {
            LOG.error("Exception starting RMI registry. Error was " + exception.getMessage(), exception);
        }
    }
```

Similarly i made change for method

```
bind()
notifyCacheAdded()
unbind()
disposeRMICachePeer()
populateListOfRemoteCachePeers()
bind()
init()
```

Comment: Thanks. So all changes in `RMICacheManagerPeerListener.java` and method you mentioned or you had to update some classes and their methods ??

Comment: Yes i had to update other bunch of classes as well.. It is difficult to explain or write the changes/code here.

Answer (score 1):

To patch support for using a custom socket factory you should remove usage of the global defaults. Static method calls on

```
java.rmi.Naming
```

should be replaced with the registry returned by the three-argument versions of

```
LocateRegistry.createRegistry
```

and

```
LocateRegistry.getRegistry
```

and in ConfigurableRMIClientSocketFactory.java change

```
getConfiguredRMISocketFactory
```

to return an SSL-based implementation.

See https://gist.github.com/okhobb/4a504e212aef86d4257c69de892e4d7d for an example patch.